# Laravel use custom functions in Resource::Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i want to use custom function in `Route::resource()` controller like with `public function check()`, `public function login()` or `public function laogout()`, but my code doesnt work, how to use custom functions?

For Example:

Route:

```
Route::resource('auth', 'AuthenticationController');
```

View:

Controller:

```
public function check()
{
    //
}
public function login()
{
    //
}
public function logout()
{
    //
}
```

I get this error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, resource controllers should be used to generate Restful API that provides CRUD interface to your application - not for logging users in and out.

Secondly, you can't add additional controller methods with **Route::resource()** - this method is used to define the prefixed set of methods - see http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers for more information.

If you want to add those custom actions to your routing, you'll need to define them separately before your resource routes, e.g.:

```
Route::get('auth/check', 'AuthenticationController@check');
```

You can read more about defining custom routes here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom function in route resource,you need to define your request type with function name,like this

```
Route::POST('auth/save-comment','authController@customFunctionName');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Of course it is possible**

You can add as many methods as you want in each controller, Larval by default adds a curd to the resource controller, methods and routers, and you need to do the following to create your own modular method in a controller.

1) First add your method publicly in the corresponding controller file

```
public function echoUser($id)
{
      return  $id;
}
```

2) In the web file of the routers folder, write and name the router, for example:

```
Route :: get ('admin / echoUser / {id}', 'UserController @ echoUser') -> name ('admin.echoUser');
```

*Note*:After adding this router, you can see it in the list of registered larval routers with the following command

```
php artisan router: list
```

3) Now you can use in the blade template file to access this method and pass id to method easily

```
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="{{route('admin.echoUser', $user-> id)}} "> Show </a>
```

**OR**

```
    <form method="get" action="{{route('admin.echoUser' , $user->id)}}">
          @csrf
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">show</button>
   </form>
```